# How can I log expensive apache processes? (something like slow_query_log for MySQL)

Tags: performance, http, optimization, apache

I have a handful of apache processes using way too much cpu.  I'd like to somehow log what's going on with these process to diagnose and debug the bottleneck.  How can I dive into what's slowing these processes down?

Example from top:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13768 apache    16   0  275m  11m 4264 S 37.4  0.1   1:22.87 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15904 apache    15   0  274m 9620 4188 S 19.8  0.1   0:14.72 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
13321 apache    16   0  275m  11m 4264 S 19.5  0.1   1:57.66 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
14552 apache    15   0  275m  11m 4244 S 19.2  0.1   0:52.49 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15794 apache    15   0  274m 9648 4200 S 18.8  0.1   0:19.94 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15296 apache    16   0  274m 9704 4256 S 18.5  0.1   0:39.45 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15782 apache    16   0  274m 9660 4208 R 18.2  0.1   0:17.56 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15797 apache    15   0  274m 9632 4184 S 17.9  0.1   0:18.35 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
14951 apache    15   0  274m 9712 4260 S 17.2  0.1   0:41.50 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15493 apache    16   0  282m  13m 4276 R 17.2  0.2   0:34.45 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15630 apache    16   0  274m 9692 4244 S 16.9  0.1   0:24.02 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
14768 apache    16   0  274m 9728 4276 S 16.6  0.1   0:52.33 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15494 apache    15   0  274m 9644 4196 S 16.6  0.1   0:36.35 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15152 apache    15   0  275m  10m 4216 S 16.0  0.1   0:39.28 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15785 apache    15   0  274m 9612 4176 S 15.7  0.1   0:20.02 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15634 apache    16   0  292m  27m 4188 R 15.0  0.3   0:22.73 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
13346 apache    15   0  275m  11m 4272 S 14.7  0.1   2:00.32 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
13068 mysql     15   0 1433m 290m 3508 S 12.8  3.5   7:45.70 mysqld                                                                                                                                                                                                             
15752 apache    16   0  287m  22m 4192 R  9.9  0.3   0:19.73 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15757 apache    15   0  275m  10m 4268 S  9.3  0.1   0:18.43 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
13841 apache    16   0  283m  18m 4268 R  6.7  0.2   1:20.26 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15742 apache    16   0  283m  18m 4264 R  6.7  0.2   0:21.13 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15903 apache    15   0  283m  18m 4220 R  6.4  0.2   0:17.96 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15987 apache    15   0  280m  13m 4212 S  2.6  0.2   0:12.98 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15751 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4284 R  2.2  0.2   0:19.02 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15986 apache    16   0  274m 9628 4180 S  2.2  0.1   0:17.88 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15872 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4220 R  1.9  0.2   0:18.79 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
16255 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4200 R  1.9  0.2   0:11.95 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
14885 apache    15   0  275m  11m 4272 S  1.6  0.1   0:44.75 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
13107 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4280 R  1.3  0.2   1:53.03 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
14160 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4304 R  1.3  0.2   0:56.41 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15407 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4276 R  1.3  0.2   0:33.79 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15770 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4200 R  1.3  0.2   0:19.03 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15985 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4284 R  1.3  0.2   0:19.56 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
14952 apache    15   0  280m  13m 4300 S  1.0  0.2   0:37.95 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15205 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4216 R  1.0  0.2   0:34.74 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15758 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4272 R  1.0  0.2   0:21.21 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15784 apache    15   0  280m  13m 4280 S  1.0  0.2   0:13.76 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
13771 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4304 R  0.6  0.2   1:16.60 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
13857 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4284 R  0.6  0.2   1:17.89 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15199 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4236 R  0.6  0.2   0:31.85 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15405 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4244 R  0.6  0.2   0:32.25 httpd                                                                                                                                                                                                              
15616 apache    16   0  280m  13m 4220 R  0.6  0.2   0:28.39 httpd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can log the time spent per request, see: [Is there a way to have Apache log slow requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878700/is-there-a-way-to-have-apache-log-slow-requests)

One process will handle many requests during its life, you have to do that kind of logging/profiling at the application level. Which technology do you use? PHP(mod_php)?

I've seen this tool recently, [Amon](http://amon.cx/) it seems very promising.